# Use WLST to create SOA EDG domain

Tags: soa, wlst, oracle-fusion-middleware

I am basically a configuration management and automation expert . I have got a task to create weblogic domains for SOA silently . The document that I have to follow is
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23943_01/core.1111/e12036/create_domain.htm#SOEDG532

I created the domain silently using a response file however oracle confirmed that JDBC cannot be configured this way and only wlst scripts can be used.

This is what I need to get using wlst script

**products**

- Basic WebLogic Server Domain
- Oracle Enterprise Manager
- Oracle WSM Policy Manager
- Oracle JRF

**Component schema**

- component schema - OWSM MDS Schema
- schema owner - DEV_MDS
- username  - abc
- password - xyz
- service listener - XXYYZZ
- port - 1554

**Admin Server**

- Name: AdminServer
- Listen Address: enter ADMINVHN.
- Listen Port: 7001
- SSL listen port: N/A

**Managed Servers**

- WLS_WSM1  xx.xx.xx.xx 7010
- WLS_WSM2  xx.xx.xx.xx 7010

**Cluster**

WSM-PM_Cluster

Assign  WLS_WSM and WLS_WSM2 to WSM-PM_Cluster

**Node MAnagers machines**

- SOAHOST1  xx.xx.xx.xx
- SOAHOST2  xx.xx.xx.xx
- ADMINHOST xx.xx.xx.xx

Assign Servers to machines

- SOAHOST1: WLS_WSM1
- SOAHOST2: WLS_WSM2
- ADMINHOST: AdminServer

Target Deployments to Clusters or Servers, the wsm-pm application is targeted to the WSM-PM_Cluster only. 
All other deployments are targeted to the AdminServer.
All JDBC system resources should be targeted to both the Admin Server and WSM-PM_Cluster.

Can some one help me with a sample script? I can build upon that . I have no experience of wlst.

Answer (score 1):

I am in the same situation. The better script that a found is in that tutorial: http://middlewaresnippets.blogspot.co.uk/2014/08/set-up-12c-soabpm-infrastructure.html

This guy automatize everything with linux bash... so some times the problem is understand what he is doing... I hope this help you

If you found a better solution let me know

Answer (score 0):

I found quite reasonable set of Chef cookbooks for WLS in [this GitHub repository](https://github.com/oracle/fmw-chef-cookbook).

Perhaps you will find it useful.

Best regards,
Jarek

Answer (score 0):

You can look at this WLST based SOA domain creation, which was excecuted on latest version. [Blog link](https://myofmwexperiments.blogspot.com/2016/01/creating-soa-and-osb-domain-1221.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can use these scripts, they combine Ansible and WLST to create a SOA domain.

https://github.com/textanalyticsman/ansible-soa

Furthermore, you should try this one , which combines Weblogic Deploy Tooling and Ansible.

https://github.com/textanalyticsman/ansible-soa-wldt